# App not running in background in IOS 7.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios7

I have developed an iPhone app using VOIP, which always runs in background. If my app running on iPhone 3GS(**IOS6**) crashes, it will restart itself in few seconds. But this is not the case on iPhone 4S(**IOS7.0.2**) i.e app is not restarting itself when it crashes.

What may be the reason behind it?

Comment: You might want to work on preventing it from crashing rather than trying to investigate the change in Apple's policy.

Comment: Furthermore, VOIP apps **explicitly don't always run in the background**. Registering as a VOIP app means you can run periodically for short periods and you'll be awoken if any traffic comes in on an open socket. If you overrun then you'll be killed just like any other app.